# Codeigniter Ajax Upload image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm currently developping some forms for my school project with CodeIgniter.

The idea is that I have a form with image upload. I'm trying to do it dynamically with Ajax but it seems not working at all. I tried the non-dynamic version with php and It works perfectly, my images are in my folder and I have no problem with it.

I tried like 5 or 6 plug-ins with no results, it is certainly my fault but I don't know where I did a mistakes.

<---Controller--->

```
if($result = $this->images_model->add_bdd())
{   
    $data['uploaded'] = $result;
    $data['message_upload'] = 'Image uploader avec succès.';                            
    $this->template->set_title('Upload successful');
    $this->template->view('add_places',$data);
}
else
{   
    $this->template->set_title('Upload failed');
    $this->template->view('add_places');
}
```

<--Model-->

```
function add_bdd()
{
    $config = array(
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|tiff',
                'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
                'max_size' => 2000,
                'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
                'overwrite' => FALSE
            );

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload())
    {

        $data_img = $this->upload->data();
        $exif = $this->exif_extractor->coords($data_img['full_path']);
        $data = array(
                'titre' => 'titlecontent',
                'url' => base_url('images/'.$data_img['file_name']),
                'url_min' => base_url('images/'.$data_img['raw_name'].'_min'.$data_img['file_ext']),
                'alt' => 'cover_contentName',
                'id_users' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
                'date_upload' => date('Y-m-d H:m'),
                'date_modified' => date('Y-m-d H:m'),
                'lat' => $exif[0],
                'long' => $exif[1],
                );
        $this->db->insert('pictures',$data);
        return $exif;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

<--View-->

```
<form action="http://localhost:8888/project/images/add" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile" value="Image de couverture"  />
<button name="upload" type="button" id="upload">Upload</button>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Place"  />
</form>
```

Can anyone give me a jQuery plugin to upload images dynamically and send back to the script my images with the path and others data that I want to return ?

I can't paste like all the code I made for jQuery, but I really need help about it. It's been 2 days that I'm on it!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help, I change my dynamic about the script so now, it works perfectly with what I have to do.

There is the script for my upload system :

<-- VIEW (upload_img)-->

```
<div id="container">
<div id="filelist"></div>
<a href="http://localhost:8888/myproject/#" id="userfile" name="userfile">[Select files]      </a>    
<a href="http://localhost:8888/myproject/images/index#" id="uploadfiles">[Upload files]</a
</div>
```

<-- CONTROLLER -->

```
function index(){
    if($this->_access())
    {
        $this->template->add_include('js/jquery.js')
                       ->add_include('js/browserplus.js')
                       ->add_include('js/plugins/plupload/plupload.full.js')
                       ->add_include('js/imgfunc.js');
        $this->template->view('upload_img');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect(site_url());
    }
}

function upload_image_spot()
{
    if($query = $this->images_model->upload_image_spot())
    {
        echo json_encode($query);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
    }
}
```

<-- MODEL -->

```
   function upload_image_spot()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH. '../images/spots');
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|tiff|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 3062;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file')) 
    // file means the file send to the website for upload, this is the name of field for Plupload script
    {
    $data_img = $this->upload->data();
    $copies = array(
            array('dir' => 'images/spots/large/', 'x' => 1000, 'y' => 600),
            array('dir' => 'images/spots/thumb/', 'x' => 100, 'y' => 60)
    );

    $this->copies($data_img,$copies);

    return 'whatever'; // Not real data, I don't wanna post them here
    }
}
```

<-- JS-SCRIPTS -->

First of all include :

-jQuery

-browserPlus

-Plupload

([Plupload Script](http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php))

Now add this script in an empty file:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    browse_button : 'userfile',
    container : 'container',
    max_file_size : '3mb',
    url : 'yourUploadFunctionCI',
    flash_swf_url : 'plugins/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : 'plugins/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG,tiff,png"},
    ]
});

uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
});

$('#uploadfiles').click(function(e) {
    uploader.start();
    e.preventDefault();
});

uploader.init();

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    $.each(files, function(i, file) {
        $('#filelist').html("");
        $('#filelist').append(
            '<div id="' + file.id + '">' +
            file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b>' +
        '</div>');
    });

    up.refresh();
});

uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html(file.percent + "%");
});

uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err, msg,file) {
    $('#filelist').append("<div>Error: " + err.code +
        ", Message: " + err.message +
        (err.file ? ", File: " + err.file.name : "") +
        "</div>"
    );
    console.log(msg,up,err);
    up.refresh();
});

uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file,response) {
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html("100%");
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.response);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Do your own customization and that's it, no need extra script like you can see on website like copy/paste all script from a php file to a controller, just add 'file' inside do_upload and everything's gonna work fine !

Have a nice day guys, hope it's help.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Does the add_bdd() function return false?

I have used CodeIgnitor to do this very thing and I have found that the filters you specify are usually why you do not get the file uploaded.  You should add more code to the section where `if ($this->upload->do_upload())` is false and print out the debug code using the following:

```
echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```

See here for more info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Keep in mind that if you are calling this via AJAX, you will need a means to see the debug result such as printing the echo'ed debug result to an HTML element on your calling page.  You could also print the iformation using a tool like Firebug.

Comment: I have no errors when I uploaded it by the normal way. I just need a plugin working with my code, I don't know how I can do achieve it. This is really special.

If you can give me an example of one of your ajax file upload, it could be useful. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Javascript code there's little anyone can do for you.

Check out [this tutorial on Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/) which goes into depth of the basic idea that you're after so that you better understand, debug and adjust your code.

Also, I barely use jQuery plugins as I find it easier to code one that better suits the needs of my current project so I can't recommend any.

Comment: Thans you @Spyros for your answer. I tried your tutorial on monday and It didn't works because jQuery is version 1.7 and the script works up to 1.2 so you have an error. I found a way to resolve my problem. I'm going to post it tomorrow with full code and explain. (much easier and up to date)